# WCF Service can not be accessed from another machine?

Tags: wcf

I have deployed wcf services in machineA and tried to accessed it through wcftestclient which is another system machineB. But i am getting error "The caller is not authenticated by wcf service". This wcf services is working fine when i testing it in machineA itself.

I have used wsHttpBinding.

How to solve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on Machine A remove security if that service is only exposed in intranet.

Add binding configuration as follows

```
<binding name="none">
    <security mode="None" />
</binding>
```

and In service add

```
bindingConfiguration="none"
```

If you don't want any security then only.

Answer (score 0):

On machine B you'll have to supply some credentials that have access to the service on A.

See this article: [Debugging Windows Authentication Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463274.aspx) for details, especially the section *Client Credentials Are Not Set Correctly* at the bottom of that document.